# how to use a certificate pem file in webdriverio with axios?

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, webdriver-io

How can i use a pem file certificate in WebdriverIO ??

Because with java I only have to register the certificate with keytool in cacerts file and that test works fine but with WebdriverIO I don't know how to register the certificate (if is necessary), by now I only have this

```
const response = await axios({
        url: 'https://hostname/api',
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
            //rejectUnauthorized: false, (if I disable this, the certificate is ignored and get the error "unable to verify the first certificate")
            requestCert: true,
            cert: fs.readFileSync('/pathcertificate.pem')
        }),
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
            
        },
        data: XMLdata
    });
```

I want to send a method post with Axios and WebdriverIO using a certificate pem file

Comment: In an https client, options `cert` and `key` are for a _client_ cert; [**for a _CA_ cert (used to validate the server) use option `ca`**](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions)

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085 thank you for your response, in this case, I only this options to get the certificate: https://tinypic.host/image/9k9t2 , how can I get the CA cert from the webpage?

Comment: I don't recognize your picture -- is that a browser, and if so which, or if not what? The browsers I use (Firefox and Chrome/Edge) do allow you to get the root CA cert (which is what nodejs 'ssl' needs, though I didn't say explicitly) but the method of selecting it differs.